# CGRectIntersectsRect() to detect first interseption

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I use `CGRectIntersectsRect()`to see whenever a `CCSprite` collides with another `CCSprite`:

```
- (void)update3
{
    for (CCSprite *sprite in _monsters)
    {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_rocket.boundingBox, sprite.boundingBox))
        {
            NSLog(@"Collide");
        }
    } 
}
```

This fires the log as long as the sprites touches each other, I just want to detect the first touch. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean be "just detecting the first touch"? - Is this just about adding `break;` to the inner if-statement?

Comment: In the tutorial you are doing, you are supposed to destroy the monster at this point. The comparison will not be executed again.

Comment: @Mundi no I'm not following any tutorial right now, I do it my own way

Comment: @MartinR I mean when the sprites touches each other the first time. So that it won't recognize it again after that first touch even if they are still touching.

Answer (score 1):

This collision code will be first called when the two objects just touch the first time. At this point, to prevent further evaluation, you could set a property on your monster, like `isInCollision` and not check for intersecting bounding rectangles when it is `true`.

When you want your monster to receive bullets again, set `isInCollision` to `false`.

Comment: I'm not used to properties, could you please give me an example

Comment: @WilhelmMichaelsen An instance variable of the class. You should have a class that either includes or inherits from CCSprite for your monsters and the rocket. In that class add a property (variable) called `isInCollision`, as Mundi suggests. Then you always know when the rocket (or the monsters, or both; however you want to set it up) is in a collision, and you know not to check again.

Comment: @WendiKidd but how can that variable detect if they are colliding?

Comment: @WilhelmMichaelsen In your code above, where you have `NSLog(@"Collide")`, add this: `if(rocket.isInCollision){return;} rocket.isInCollision = true;`. *You* can tell when they are colliding. If you detect a collision and the rocket is already in a collision, you force a return. If it is the *first* collision, you set the variable to true so that when you detect it the second time, you know to return.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob but I don't even know how to create that kind of property

Comment: You cannot program a game if you do not know about properties. Please accept this answer and ask a new one if necessary (but perhaps better to go through some simple tutorials). If you are serious about iOS programming, check out the free online Stanford course.